# The comparison of "lesser than" and "less than" and "smaller than"

Tags: adjectives

I have come across this sentence in a dictionary:

> "She has little love for him. Certainly, her love for him is lesser
> than her love for her mother."

I wonder if these are also OK

> "She has little love for him. Certainly, her love for him is less than
> her love for her mother."
>
> "She has little love for him. Certainly, her love for him is smaller
> than her love for her mother."

Is there a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Love doesn't have "sizes," so "smaller" definitely doesn't work. And "lesser" is a judgement of *quality* meaning that the thing is *less important or meaningful*, whereas "less" is a judgement of *quantity* meaning that the thing is *of a smaller amount*. While both make sense in this context (either her love for him is *of a lesser quality* that her love for her mother, or she has *less love* for him than for her mother, they don't always have the same meaning.